# How to launch caching of many pages on Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, zend-cache

I have an "article" controller and a "view" action. My action takes an id parameter, allowing the visitor to view the article with a specific id (get the info from a mysql database).
I want to create a script that generates all my caches instantly. Indeed, I don't want to wait that my visitors visit the articles for my cache files to be generated.
Any hint of how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron job / scheduled task and generate them in intervals of your choosing.